# Print Unicode character in Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache Poi to READ Excel file.
In my excel file has a row with string value : "ありがとう"

I use this method to print value :

```
cell.getStringCellValue()
```

The result : "?????"

I try to use method :

```
new String(cell.getStringCellValue().getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8")
```

The same result  appear.

Do anyone how to solve this problem, please to help me ?

Thank all.

Comment: That code is wrong; in Java String always contains Unicode, here 5 characters. And starts using an encoding when creating bytes. If the target encoding cannot represent the Unicode symbol, such question mark may be written. If POI does not work it might be the font too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your console not support the charset this string represent.
in Windows, change the console to utf8 page by `chcp 65001`